# How to make Job Simultaneously per HTTP Request by Python

Tags: python, http

I'm making a server code for chatbot from Telegram API using Python. currently, my program runs synchronously does a job per single HTTP request. If I made 3 requests from chatbot the 2nd one doesn't execute on my program. It happened when 1st request isn't completed yet.

```
def main():
    last_update_id = None
    while True:
        updates = get_updates(last_update_id)
        if len(updates["result"]) > 0:
            last_update_id = get_last_update_id(updates) + 1 // this code to get latest request api
            text, chat, username = get_last_chat_id_and_text(get_updates())
            print(username+" "+text)
        .
        .
        .
            //do the process//
            .
        .
        .
        .
```

I want to make all requests are executed (do process)

Answer (score 0):

To be able to handle many requests, try submit your `//do the process//` to either `ThreadPoolExecutor` or `ProcessPoolExecutor`. You can find them in [concurrent.futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) module.

If it's more like I/O processing than you should be fine with threads. If it's more like heavy computing you'd be better with processes.